# Area of Square Proof using Picks Theorem.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is my logic correct below to prove the [Area_of_Square](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Square)? Thanks.

Applying [Picks Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicksTheorem.html)

Let **A** be the area of a simply closed lattice square. Let **B** denote the number of lattice points on the square edges and **I** the number of points in the interior of the square. Then

$A=I + \frac{B}{2}-1$

Suppose a square has integer side length $ L \in \mathbb{N}$, it has the following pattern:
[image: Square Lattice]

```
L=1 B=4  I=0  A=1
L=2 B=8  I=1  A=4
L=3 B=12 I=4  A=9
L=4 B=16 I=9  A=16
L=5 B=20 I=16 A=25
L=6 B=24 I=25 A=36
...
```

The number of boundary points $\textbf B = 4L$, the interior points $\textbf I = (L-1)^2$.
Plugging these into Picks Theorem yields:

\begin{align*}
A &=(L-1)^2+(\frac{4L}{2})-1\\
  &=(L^2-2L+1)+(2L)-1\\
  &=L^2
\end{align*}

∎

Comment: In its current form, no. Hard to say in what sense it would be a proof since $L^2$ is commonly taken to be the area of a square of side $L$ *by definition*. But putting that aside, how do you prove your table of relationships between L, B, I?

Comment: I was hoping that proving the relationship between L,B,I could easily be done by a real mathematician. ;) I just noticed that simple pattern when I was dabbling with applying Picks Theorem to derive Pythagoras Theorem.  (if possible) Thanks.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Square

Comment: I'm sure it can, but you asked if the proof you presented was a proof! Although I'm not sure it's true - what if your square is not aligned with the axes?

Comment: If not aligned with the axes, then it's not possible to determine any pattern for the points B and I, so Picks theorem isn't applicable. However, if aligned, the B and I pattern exists, and Picks will compute the square area as $L^2$. Thanks.